# Django - Access list values on template

Tags: arrays, django, list, templates

I've to get access to all values availables in a `list(array)` in a Django template. All examples I find online, use dictionaries instead. So, the list is passed correctly to the template, but the following code doesn't work:

```
{% for item in array %}
    field_names = field_names + "{{ item }},";
    {% if forloop.last %}
        field_names = field_names + "{{ item }}";
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I could access the values using `{{ field.[0] }}` , `{{ field.[1] }}` , etc. But, I have to make it work independently of the list's size.

Can anybody give me a hint?

P.S. - I cannot use a dictionary to pass the values to the template, since that code wasn't donne by me, and I'm not supposed to touch it.

Comment: Is this contained in a Javascript block? What is your desired output?

Comment: Yes, it is contained in a Javascript block. I'm automating the process of building jqGrids, so the variable `field_names` is going to be used inside a jqGrid attribute. Thanks for you attention.

Comment: So what is in the list? What happens when you pass the list directly to the JS? What is wrong with the code you have now?

Comment: The list has the following information `["value1","value2", "value3"]`, and i wanted to use the list to build a string exactly like this `"value1","value2","value3"`. With the for cycle above I intended to do just that. But on my debugger i can see that none of the values is passed to the variable `field_names`.

Comment: But that is perfectly valid as a parameter to the Javascript already. Why are you bothering with all this code?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to python/Django. Yes it's valid. But the values inside field_names will be used inside other javascript value. Something like this `collNames: ['id','key', {{ field_names }} ], `. If use the variable that comes from the view directly is gives me error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it!! I just passed the variable to the template exactly as i needed it and used `{{ array|safe }}` to resolve it to a Javascript variable. Done!

Answer (score 0):

In your view:

```
my_joined_list = ",".join(somelist)
```

In your template:

```
field_names = {{ my_joined_list }}
```

Comment: Because I need the values separated by aposthrophe I add the following code `my_joined_list = "','".join(somelist)`, but didn't work. I notice that it adds two **//** before each aposthrophe .